# Scrape Javascript Commentouts with Scrapy+Splash

Tags: javascript, python, scrapy, render, splash-screen

I'm in a trouble with extracting javascript commentouts.
Tools I'm using is a combination of Scrapy and Splash.
After rendering javascript to html, commentout still is not available to be extracted.
Source code is as follows.

```
</div><br clear="all"><a href="http://api.gogo.gs"><img 

src="http://api.gogo.gs/images/api_125x17.png" border="0"></a> <a href="http://www.gnavi.co.jp/">
<img src="http://apicache.gnavi.co.jp/image/rest/b/api_155_20.gif" width="155" height="20" border="0" alt="グルメ情報検索サイト　ぐるなび"></a> <a href="http://www.hotpepper.jp/"><img src="http://api.hotpepper.jp/content/images/hp_api_s.gif" alt="ホットペッパー Webサービス" width="155" height="20" border="0" title="ホットペッパー Webサービス"></a> <a href="http://apiblog.kakaku.com/"><img src="http://img.tabelog.com/images/banner/tabelog_api_135x17.gif " alt="食べログ.com WEB サービス" title="食べログ.com WEB サービス" border="0"></a> 
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
window.onload=function(){
fill('/Ajax/gasoline.php?lat=42.99461&lng=142.8565','gasolineInfo');
fill('/Ajax/restaurant.php?lat=42.99461&lng=142.8565&offset=1','restaurantInfo');
fill('/Ajax/hotel.php?lat=42.99461&lng=142.8565','hotelInfo');
_map = new Y.Map("ic-map-box",{configure : {doubleClickZoom : true,}});
_map.addControl(new Y.LayerSetControl());
_map.addControl(new Y.ScaleControl());
_map.addControl(new Y.SliderZoomControlVertical());
_map.drawMap(new Y.LatLng(42.99461,142.8565), 10, Y.LayerSetId.NORMAL);
var marker = new Y.Marker(new Y.LatLng(42.99461,142.8565));
 marker.bindInfoWindow("<br><a href=\"ic.php?ic=%E5%8D%81%E5%8B%9D%E6%B8%85%E6%B0%B4\">十勝清水</a><br><a href=\"route.php?f=%E5%8D%81%E5%8B%9D%E6%B8%85%E6%B0%B4&t=&c=%E6%99%AE%E9%80%9A%E8%BB%8A\">出発ICにする</a><br><a href=\"route.php?f=&t=%E5%8D%81%E5%8B%9D%E6%B8%85%E6%B0%B4&c=%E6%99%AE%E9%80%9A%E8%BB%8A\">到着ICにする</a><br>");
 _map.addFeature(marker);

}
// -->
</script>
</div></div><div id="seesaaAdE" class="seesaaAdE"></div>
```

I need what's in between `<!--//-->` after `<script type="text/javascript">`, especially this part `lat=42.99461&lng=142.8565` in `fill('/Ajax/gasoline.php?lat=42.99461&lng=142.8565','gasolineInfo');`.
Any idea would save me! Thanks!

Comment: I'd suggest that you try to intercept `fill` function when doing ajax call to `gasoline.php` .. so no scraping but intercept the event and then read `lat` & `lng`

Comment: @KresimirPendic Thanks! but I don't really get your suggestion.. can you just give me more details? appreciate that

Comment: `response.css('script')` and you have it as normal string. You can use standard functions like `some_text.find('lat=')` or use regex `re.search()`. BTW: it should work even without Splash. If you need something more then you should read data directly from url `/Ajax/gasoline.php?lat=42.99461&lng=142.8565'`

Comment: @furas genius! thanks! and it would be appreciated if you could tell me how to remove <value></value> when i export it as a XML file.

Comment: where do you have `<value>` ? you can use `text.replace("<value>", "")` or if it is at the beginng of text to using slicing `text[7:]`, if you have many different tags then you can use modules like `lxml`/`BeautifulSoup` to parse it and search data similar to `response.css()` or `response.xpath()`

Comment: @furas thanks a lot! you saved me!

Comment: I'd drop splash as soon as you can. It's a nightmare. It's a python program with a LUA interpreter slapped on it for some reason.You may as well use selenium. Although splash is a bit faster it still gets detected as an outdated browser by most sites.

Comment: @eusid yea? didn't really know that...thanks for your advice!

Comment: There's few instances I'd use splash just because it works so well with scrapy, but if you need proxies for it you must write a LUA script. Also, many sites must have their interfaces automated and the only way to do that again is with a LUA script. So for the sake of simplicity I always try to do with scrapy first. Always look for end points like furas said and if u need more than what scrapy can do consider Selenium.